# Grunt can't run SASS (grunt-contrib-sass)

Tags: compilation, sass, gruntjs, gruntfile, grunt-contrib-sass

I have configured my Gruntfile.js with this module, but when I run Grunt it's not working, it stops. This is my code:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'), 
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'assets/css/estilos.css' : 'assets/css/scss/*.scss'
                }
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.registerTask('sass', ['sass']);
};
```

I have it installed with `-g` and `--save-dev`, so, this it what happened:

http://subefotos.com/ver/?2587793b6c11cd7a7b11535357c1354co.jpg

Grunt stays "stand-by", nothing happens, no lines, no errors, no warnings, just write `grunt sass` and then freeze. I can stop it with Ctrl + C but nothing more.

Which is it the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Any error log or warnnings?

Comment: Do not post screenshots of errors.

Comment: No, there isn't an error log or warning. Grunt just stays like that, nothing happen, no error, no lines... Nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct syntax for files?  Because Sass won't compile .css files at all.

Comment: I mean, SASS compile scss of course, and then makes css, look to the github of sass

`grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: {
        'main.css': 'main.scss'
      }
    }
  }
});`

Comment: Did you make a task called 'sass' by any chance? Like `grunt.registerTask('sass', ['sass'])`. I did that and after I removed it I was fine.

Comment: Of course I did, I don' want it in default.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you using [Grunt-SASS](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) instead of grunt-contrib-sass.
Its a binary compiler for sass. I am using it for a while and works fine.

Comment: What is the diference between them.

Comment: A binary complier. Faster and better for who has problems installing Ruby.. Specially on Windows.

Comment: If I change it now, will it break the project?

Comment: @Lydia Nope, it will work fine. You also can revert back